# How to use <mvc:resource/> in Groovy

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, groovy, gradle

I want to use `<mvc:resource/>` such as `<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/" />` `<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />` in `context-mvc.groovy`,and I do not know how to write.help me~

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver

beans {
    xmlns context: "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"


    context."component-scan"("base-package" : "com.oberon.fm")

    viewResolver(InternalResourceViewResolver) {
        prefix = "/pages/"
        suffix = ".jsp"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the mvc namespace in your Groovy, you need to add it the the `xmlns`.

Then you can use it just like the context one.

```
beans {

    xmlns([ctx:'http://www.springframework.org/schema/context',
           mvc:'http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc'])

    ctx.'component-scan'('base-package': "com.oberon.fm")
    mvc.resources(mapping:"/images/**", location:"/images/")
    mvc.resources(mapping:"/resources/**", location:"/resources/")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question,I am a learner of spring,sometimes i feel difficult,thanks to these enthusiastic people  especially you.And i have another problem,my DipatcherServlet  <url-pattern>is " /",then when i usemvc.resources(mapping:"/images/**", location:"/images/"),my viewResolver does not work

Comment: import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver

beans {
 xmlns ([context: "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context",
 mvc:  "http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"])
 mvc.resources(mapping:"/images/**", location:"/images/")
 mvc.resources(mapping:"/css/**", location:"/css/")
 context."component-scan"("base-package" : "com.oberon.fm")

 viewResolver(InternalResourceViewResolver) {
  prefix = "/pages/"
  suffix = ".jsp"
 }
}